# Continuous function with linear directional derivatives=>Total differentiability?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

As in the title: 
If $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous in $x$ and has directional derivatives $\partial_vf(x)=L(v)\,\forall v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, where $L$ is linear, does this imply that $f$ is totally differentiable?

Comment: notice the criteria "linear" is important. I think there exist sick examples where the directional derivatives exist in all directions, however, they don't glue together nicely. Linearity forces continuity hence the result. For example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372070/f-not-differentiable-at-0-0-but-all-directional-derivatives-exist?rq=1

Comment: yes, you're correct, my (now deleted) post assumed the partials exist near the point, in fact, that calculation shows that bounded partials existing near a point imply continuity at the point (which is interesting). However, the question you ask is different, I'm sure someone will address it soon.

Comment: If all partial derivatives of a continuous function exist and at most one is not continuous, the map is differentiable. And this result is optimal.

Comment: I thought of this example before searching on MSE: $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\exp\left(-\left(\frac{y-x^2}{x^3}\right)^2\right)$$ But I prefer John's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is "no".

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x,x^2)=x$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$ and $f(x,y)=0$ if $y\neq x^2$. This function $f$ is continuous at $0$ with $f(0)=0$. For any fixed direction $v$, we have $f(tv)=0$ if $t$ is small enough; so $\partial_v f(0)$ exists with $\partial_vf(0)=0$. But $f$ is not differentiable at $0$ because the only possible (total) differential is $L=0$ and we don't have $f(x,y)=o(\Vert (x,y)\Vert)$ as $(x,y)\to 0$.

Comment: You are right, thanks. Could my conjecture be saved by adding continuity everywhere?

Comment: This, I don't know...

Comment: @Bananach I don't think that adding continuity fixes it, I conjecture you could smooth out the discontinuity hence obtaining an example which is continuous everywhere yet still possesses the non-differentiability at (0,0) with all directional derivatives existing. I'm thinking of using a bump function with a width which decreases to zero as you approach the origin, yet has finite width as you travel along $y=x^2$ for finite distance away from $(0,0)$. I haven't worked out the details... but, does this make sense?

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Your idea works.  $U = \{(x,y) : \frac{1}{2}x^2 < y < 2x^2\}$ is open.  $F = \{(x,x^2) : -1 \le x \le 1\}$ is closed.  Define a function on $U^c \cap F$ to be $x$ on $(x,x^2)$ and $0$ elsewhere.  This is continuous.  By the Tietze extension theorem, we may extend this to a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  By the same argument, it cannot be differentiable, but all directional derivatives will exist.

Comment: @Bananach If you require that the function is locally lipschitz at the point where the directional derivatives are defined, then your conjecture works.

Comment: @user3281410 thank you for adding to the discussion here. Most appreciated.

Comment: @user3281410 I think you meant the union of F and $ U^{c}$. Thanks for the input. Is there a short argument why Lipschitz does the trick?

Comment: @Bananach Yes you were right about what I meant to type, but I can't edit it now.  The argument is similar to the last step in one proof of Rademacher's theorem, which states that locally Lipschitz functions on an open subset of $R^n$ are almost everywhere differentiable.  It's not that long, but it won't fit into this box.

Comment: @Bananach It is probably no longer relevant to you, but may be to others (myself included) who found this thread: a proof of the statement for Lipschitz functions can be found in [Cui, Pang – Modern Nonconvex Nondifferentiable Optimization, Proposition 4.1.1].

Answer (score 10):

The answer is "no."

Let $f: R^2 \to R$ be defined by $f(x,y)= \frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2}$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0) = 0$.  This function is continuous; its directional derivative is defined at each point in every direction; and at each point its directional derivative is a linear function of the direction.  But, you can check that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$ by approaching $(0,0)$ along $y=x^2$.

See *Foundations of Modern Analysis* by Dieudonne, Vol. 1 Chapter VIII Section 4.