# Continuity everywhere+partial derivatives in one point$\implies$Total differentiability in this point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous everywhere. If we know that in one single point $x_0$ all the partial derivatives exist and are linear, $\partial_vf(x_0)=L(v)$, does this imply that $f$ is totally differentiable in $x_0$?

In a previous question, user Etienne gave an example that showed that the continuity of $f$ everywhere rather than just in $x_0$ is necessary.

Comment: Do you mean directional derivatives?

Comment: What do you mean by the previous Question here?

Comment: @Kumar https://math.stackexchange.com/q/447104/87023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is still "no". In fact, we can smooth out Etienne's example from the previous question.

Let $B\colon\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ be a smooth bump function supported on $[0,2]$ such that $B(1) = 1$. Now let $f(x,y)=xB(y/x^2)$.

Comment: What do you mean by the previous Question here?

Comment: @Kumar https://math.stackexchange.com/a/447197/87023