# Directional Derivative and differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

My question is similar, but not equal to this...[Question on linearity of directional derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447104/continuous-function-with-linear-directional-derivatives-total-differentiability)

Let $f'_{h}(a)$ be the directional derivative. And for the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$f'_{h}(a)=\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{ \partial f}{\partial x_i}(a) \cdot h_i$

Is f differentiable at $a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't. The linked question gives a counterexample. But it is true if $$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(a+th)-f(a)}{t}$$

converges uniformly for all $h$ in the unit ball.

**Edit:** I'll include a proof.

Put $v:=\frac{h}{\|h\|}$. Then we have $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)h}{\|h\|}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+\|h\|v)-f(a)}{\|h\|}-Df(a)\left(\frac{h}{\|h\|}\right)= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+\|h\|v)-f(a)}{\|h\|}-Df(a)v=0$$

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking, but do you know of a book that explains well multivariate analysis? Which one do you use. The one I use leaves many things hidden. A book that gives intuition, and still remains some formalism would be great.

Comment: And if it converges uniformly, then the directional derivative is continuous, which in this exercise, it will make the partial derivatives continuous. Hence the function would be C^1 which implies differentiability. I am correct?

Comment: But how can I be sure that f is continuous on a neighbourhood of point a?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Not sure if I can help you with a reference. Most the books I know are in German. You could try Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Uniform convergence doesn't guarantee continuity of the partial derivatives. It makes sure that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{\|h\|}-Df(a)h=0$, where $Df(a)$ is the Jacobian.

Comment: How? I'm sorry I'm not seeing. Could you help me?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I provided a proof

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Book recommendations for multivariable analysis: Multidimensional real analysis by Duistermaat, volumes [one](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0521551145/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pd_S_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=Q2UKDXIIA8N&coliid=I2N4YZC5J6JCIK) and [two](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0521829259/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pd_S_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=Q2UKDXIIA8N&coliid=I29HWEAJKLN01N), Analysis in vector spaces, by [Mustafa](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0470486775/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pd_nS_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=Q2UKDXIIA8N&coliid=IBUGP43JAJ10Q)...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. ...[Introduction to mathematical analysis](http://www.amazon.com/dp/3034806353/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_S_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=Q2UKDXIIA8N&coliid=IUPVAZMNBA2T1) by Kriz, [Differential forms](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0123944031/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pd_S_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=Q2UKDXIIA8N&coliid=I37IZ13HZNHE4W) by Weintraub and [Multivariable analysis](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0857291912/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_nS_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=Q2UKDXIIA8N&coliid=I2ACX53U3YLWWR) by Satish.

Comment: @Fantini, Obrigado. ;)

Comment: @VincentBoelens, I understood your comment, but what I didn't understood was the relation with uniform convergence. Now I think I get it. With unif. conv, I'm sure that lim goes to zero since $sup_{||h||\leq 1} |\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{||h||}-Df(a)h| \rightarrow 0$, as h goes to zero. Many Thanks, Vincent Boelens