# Can we define differentiation without using a norm?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Since all norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent, the following question makes sense:

> Can we define the notion of "differentiability" of a map $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ without refering to a norm at all? Can we define the derivative itself?

(That is, without mentioning any kind of norm, or a distance induced by it).

In fact, I guess that one could ask that even for $n=1$.

Comment: Differentiation is a statement saying "for $h$ close enough to $0$, we can approximate $f(x+h)$ by $f(x) + u(h)$ with $u$ linear continuous". So you have to say what "close enough" and "approximate" stand for. And what continuous stands for $u$ linear.

Maybe there exists purely topological notion for all of that, but I did not ever hear about.

Comment: I think you would like to have this new notion equivalent to the previous one. 
Now Diffrentiation is a method of approximation of the $\mathbb R^n\xrightarrow[]{f} \mathbb R$  by a linear funcntion $\mathbb R^n \xrightarrow[]{Df_x} \mathbb R$ at point $x\in \mathbb R^n$. And the moment you say approximation you need a notion of **distance**.

Comment: @Dldier if such a topological notion exist then you might be able to have a notion of differentiability on any topological space (not only manifolds) isn't it ?

Comment: The closest I can think of is Caratheordory's definition of differentiability. Namely, let $I$ be an interval, $f$ defined on $I$, and $a\in I$; then $f$ is differentiable at $a$ iff there is a continuous function $\phi(x)$ defined on $I$ such that $f(x)-f(a)=\phi(x) (x-a)$. This requires only the notions of interval and continuity, which can be given topologically.

Comment: Are you willing to accept the differentiable structures, making the domain and target smooth manifolds? In that case, one should view the derivative as a map between tangent spaces.

Comment: [Differentiation of a mapping - Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Differentiation_of_a_mapping).

Comment: You could use a construction analogous to that of the [Zariski tangent space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_tangent_space), but the catch is that your set of "differentiable" functions is going to be limited. That said, you could probably extend beyond defining the derivative on polynomial functions if you consider the derivative as a formal operator on power series, but we can't really say that these power series "equal" anything without some kind of topology.

Comment: The notion of "limit" does not require distance, only topology. The article @CalumGilhooley linked to explains notions of derivative of maps between topological vector spaces. Interestingly, these notes explain why the only topological vector space structure on a finite dimensional vector space comes from (any of the equivalent) norms: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/topology/finite-dim-TVS.pdf ...It seems to me that a derivative does require some sort of linear structure, though. In the differentiable manifold setting, the tangent space gives the linear structure.

Comment: I doubt it. A topological space can be freely stretched, and that would change the "slope".

Answer (score 7):

Here is an attempt to correct the below definition. Recall that $f$ is differentiable at $x \in \Bbb R^n$ if there exists a linear map $A:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ such that for $y \in \Bbb R^n$, the error function
$$
\varepsilon(y) = f(x + y) - f(x) - A(y) 
$$
satisfies $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\varepsilon(y)}{\|y\|} = 0$. It is this limit condition, however, that needs to be encoded in a different way.

It is implied in this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Generalization_to_topological_vector_spaces) (linked in the comment below) that we can replace this limit condition with the statement that $\varepsilon:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is *tangent to 0*. That is, for every neighborhood $W \subset \Bbb R$ of $0$, there exists a neighborhood $U \subset \Bbb R^n$ of $0$, a function $o:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with $\lim_{t \to 0} o(t)/t = 0$, and a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|t| < \delta$, $\varepsilon(tU) \subset o(t) W$.

We can make things a bit more concrete since the domain is simply $\Bbb R$.  For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a neighborhood $U \subset \Bbb R^n$ of $0$, a function $o:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with $\lim_{t \to 0} o(t)/t = 0$, and a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|t| < \delta$, $\frac{|\varepsilon(tU)|}{o(t)} < \epsilon$.

---

*Note: as Asaf notes in his comment, this is **not** a correct definition of differentiability. In particular, there are functions that satisfy this condition but fail to be differentiable.*

We could stick to the product topology over $\Bbb R^n$ rather than considering norms.

Recall that we say that a function $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is differentiable at $x \in \Bbb R^n$ if there exists a linear map $A: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ such that for every vector $v \in \Bbb R^n$,
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + hv) - f(x) - hAv}{h} = 0.
$$
With the topological definition of a limit, we might frame this as follows:

> The function $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is differentiable at $x \in \Bbb R^n$ if there exists a linear map $A: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ such that for every vector $v \in \Bbb R^n$ and every neighborhood $U \subset \Bbb R^n$ of $0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $0<|h| < \delta$, we have
>   $$
> \frac{f(x + hv) - f(x) - hAv}{h} \in U.
> $$
>   We define the derivative of $f$ at $x$ to be the linear map $f'(x) = A$.

---

We can view the different norm-definitions as arising from different choices of neighborhood bases.

For example, we can derive the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ (max-norm) definition as follows. Because the sets $U = (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \times \cdots \times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ form a neighborhood basis of $0 \in \Bbb R^n$, we can simplify this definition as follows:

> The function $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is differentiable at $x \in \Bbb R^n$ if there exists a linear map $A: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ such that for every vector $v \in \Bbb R^n$ and every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $|h| < \delta$, the entries of $\frac{f(x + hv) - f(x) - hAv}{h}$ lie between $-\epsilon$ and $\epsilon$, or equivalently we have $\|\frac{f(x + hv) - f(x) - hAv}{h}\|_\infty < \epsilon$.

If we instead consider the neighborhood basis of open spheres, we can derive the Euclidean-norm definition as follows:

> The function $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is differentiable at $x \in \Bbb R^n$ if there exists a linear map $A: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ such that for every vector $v$, unit-vector $w \in \Bbb R^n$, and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $|h| < \delta$,
>   $$
> -\epsilon < w^T\left[\frac{f(x + hv) - f(x) - hAv}{h}\right] < \epsilon,
> $$ 
>   or equivalently we have $\|\frac{f(x + hv) - f(x) - hAv}{h}\|_2 < \epsilon$.

Comment: But you speak of unit vectors, so vectors of *norm* 1...

Comment: @JensRenders See my latest edit. There is no need to consider unit vectors (except when we are discussing the Euclidean norm)

Comment: Good edit. I suppose this is equivalent to demanding that the sequence $\left(n(f(x + v/n) - f(x) - Av)\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to zero for all $v$.

Comment: @JensRenders That doesn't quite work; we can build some pathological counterexamples. It does suffice to consider all sequences $h_n \to 0$, though.

Comment: Interesting, can you give such a counterexample or point me to it?

Comment: @Jens Here's an example of a function whose limit at zero fails to exist even though $f(c/n) \to 0$ for every $c \in \Bbb R$. Find a bounded sequence $(a_n)$ of non-zero reals such that we never have $a_j/m = a_k/n$ with $j,k,m,n \in \Bbb N$ (this might require the axiom of choice).  Define $f$ so that $f(a_n/k) = k$ when $j \leq n$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Jens That should be a sequence of **positive** real numbers. Also $f(a_n/k) = k$ when $k \leq n$.

Comment: Thank you. Shouldn't it be $A(hv)$ instead of $Av$ though?

Comment: @Asaf Yes (see my latest edit), and I realize now that with this “directional derivative” definitition, we can actually move the $Av$ to the other side of the equation, so that the derivative is defined to be a linear map whose output matches a certain limit.

Comment: Actually, on a second thought, I don't think that your definition works. It only implies existence and linearity of directional derivatives. However, this does not imply (total) differentiability in general-https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447104/continuous-function-with-linear-directional-derivatives-total-differentiability.

Comment: @AsafShachar I should have thought of that... thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Why you choose the name Omnomnomnom ?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That's OK. I unaccepted your answer for the moment. I am still grateful for the nice attempt.

Comment: @Sou I just thought that it's a funny name and it's fun to say

Comment: It is fun. Whenever i read that i just imagine pacman :) Nice answer btw.

Comment: @AsafShachar Does this link do the trick? It's a definition of the Fréchet derivative between topological vector spaces. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Generalization_to_topological_vector_spaces

Comment: @PhillipAndreae That's a great find; I wish I had thought to look to functional analysis.