# A continuous function with all directional derivatives but NOT differentiable??

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I need a function $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ continuous in $\Bbb R^2$, and such that all its directional derivatives exist, but $f$ must not be differentiable in $\Bbb R^2$.

I know examples of functions continuous but not diff., and with all directional derivatives but not diff. But I cant find an example which satisfy all those conditions at the same time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372070/f-not-differentiable-at-0-0-but-all-directional-derivatives-exist?rq=1

Comment: If you put the title of your post in a search engine and clicked a few results, you'd have an answer in less time than it took to type this question.

Comment: Do you want it to be nowhere differentiable, or not differentiable at one point ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, even though all directional derivatives exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372070/show-that-fracx3x2y2-is-not-differentiable-at-0-0-even-though-al)