# Prove function is not differentiable even though all directional derivatives exist and it is continuous.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

In the following [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions), the function below is provided as an example of a function being continuous and all directional derivatives existing. Yet, it is not differentiable. How do I prove that this is not differentiable?

$$
f(x,y)= 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{y^3}{x^2+y^2},& \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Hint: the definition of differentiability is something you could check explicitly. If the derivative existed, it would have a very particular form. Can you use this? I'll give a complete answer in a bit if you're still stuck.

Comment: @AlfredYerger - derivative existed? Isn't there no single "derivative" in this case since it is two dimensional?

Comment: In multivariable calculus, "derivative" refers to the total derivative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative.

Comment: Try taking the limit along different curves through the origin, something like $y=x$ or $x=y^2.$ Does the limit behave differently in these cases. For the derivative, you are allowed to approach the origin along any path, not just along straight lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$f$ not differentiable at $(0,0)$ but all directional derivatives exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372070/f-not-differentiable-at-0-0-but-all-directional-derivatives-exist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of the directional derivative at $0$ is 
$$df(v)=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f(tv)-f(0)}{t}$$ if $v=(a,b)$ then

$$\frac{f(tv)-f(0)}{t}=\frac{\frac{t^3a^3}{t^2a^2+t^2b^2}}{t}=\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}$$

So  the directional derivative is 
$$df(a,b)=\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}$$
Now the condition for differentiablity is that $df$ is a linear function. This is not the case so the function is not differentiable, although all directional derivatives exist.

I had a minor realization about this recently, if you take for example $z=f(x,y)$ and graph it as a surface and if directional derivatives of $f$ exist then then the surface will have slopes in all directions. So there are well defined tangent lines in all directions. However the function is differentiable only if all those tangent lines lie on the same plane. If you graph this function in wolfram alpha you can see that this is not the case, as was also shown above.

Comment: More to the point, the function is differentiable at a point iff its graph has a tangent **plane** at that point, not just tangent lines in every direction. =)

Comment: @user21820 I said that $df$ is linear iff all tangent lines lie is a plane, thus forming a tangent plane. In the example given the lines do not lie in a plane. So there is no tangent plane. So I am not sure what you are trying to communicate to me in this comment.

Comment: I'm just giving a 1-line summary of your post, because it may be clearer to some people if you say "tangent plane" instead of "all tangent lines lie in a plane". That's all! Nothing wrong with your post at all! =)

Comment: @user21820 Oh ok fine, that is the inference I hoped people would draw.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus should be $\frac{b^3}{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: I think your denominator in the limit should be $t||v||$, not just $t$.

Answer (score 4):

The derivative at the origin, if it exists, is given by limit

$$ \lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)} \frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0) -f_x(0,0)h-f_y(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{\frac{k^3}{h^2+k^2}-0-0\cdot h-1\cdot k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

Does that limit exist?

Comment: Let $k=r sin(\theta)$ and $h=r cos(\theta)$. The limit becomes $sin^3(\theta)$. And this doesn't exist because it depends on $\theta$?

Comment: That works.  Well done.

Comment: Just a minor detail: I think the partial derivative $f_y(0,0)$ is not $0$.

Comment: @FYY Good catch.  I've edited accordingly.  Thank you.  Much appreciative.