# Prove $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ has directional derivatives in $(0,0)$ but is not differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{2x^2y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}, & \mbox{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0) ,  \\ 0, & \mbox{if } (x,y) =(0,0)\end{cases}$$

be a function from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that in $(0,0)$ the function $f$ has directional derivatives in all directions. But $f$ is not differentiable in $(0,0)$. For the first question  I try to show that for $v=(x,y)$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$D_{v}(f)=lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(0+tv)-f(0)}{t}$$.

exist. This proves directional derivatives that in $(0,0)$ directional derivatives exist in any direction right? But I cant prove this limit is $0$. So far:

$$\frac{f(0+tv)-f(0)}{t}=\frac{f(tv)}{t}=\frac{f(tx,ty)}{t}=\frac{\frac{2(tx)^{2}(ty)}{(tx)^{2}+(ty)^{2}}}{t}=\frac{2x^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}.$$

Then $D_{v}(f)=lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(0+tv)-f(0)}{t}$ exist and is equal to the constant $\frac{2x^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$. This proves directional derivatives exist in $(0,0)$ in all directions. In order to show that $f$ is not differentiable in $(0,0)$, I attempted to prove $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$. But cant find the path to prove this, for instance $$lim_{t \to 0}f(t,t)=lim_{t \to 0} t=0=f(0,0)$$ also tried $$lim_{t \to 0}f(t^{3},t)=lim_{t \to 0} t^{3}=0=f(0,0)$$.

Comment: But in order to prove directional derivatives in all direction exist the limit should  $0$ as $t \to 0$, right? @Joe

Comment: No, for the first part you just need to show that in "each" direction, the directional derivative exists, meaning that the limit in the limit definition of the derivative exists.

Comment: There are MANY similar questions on this site. Have you checked any of them? For instance: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678774/prove-function-is-not-differentiable-even-though-all-directional-derivatives-exi

Comment: @Joe Thanks Joe! I already edited my question to show directional derivatives exist in $(0,0)$ at any direction. The constant I get is the same you got?

Comment: Yes, that's the same constant I get. You will not be able to show that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$, since it is. If $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, then $\left| \frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le \frac{2r^3}{r^2}=2r$. So for the second part, see the posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)$ be defined as

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}, &(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\\\0,& (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

The directional derivative of $f(x,y)$ along the unit vector $(a,b)$ (i.e. $a^2+b^2=1$) at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is given by the limit

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(ah,bh)-f(0,0)}{h}&=2\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{a^2h^2bh}{a^2h^2+b^2h^2}}{h}\\\\
&=\frac{2a^2b}{a^2+b^2}\\\\
&=2a^2b
\end{align}$$

So, the directional derivatives exist in all directions at the origin.

---

It is easy to show that both first partial derivatives vanish at the origin.  It remains to show that the limit

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-f_1(0,0)h-f_2(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

fails to exist.  Proceeding we see that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-f_1(0,0)h-f_2(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}&=\frac{2h^2k}{(h^2+k^2)^{3/2}}\\\\
&=2\frac{h^2}{h^2+k^2}\frac{k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\tag1
\end{align}$$

Now, if $h=k$, the limit of $(1)$ is $2^{-1/2}$ while if $h=0$ or $k=0$ the limit is $0$.  Inasmuch as the limit of $(1)$ fails to exist, we conclude that $f$ is not differentiable.

Comment: For future readers: looking at $h=k$ is sufficient to disprove (1), no need of $h=0$ or $k=0.$

Comment: It is sufficient to prove that the limit (if any) is not $0,$ and that is all we need here.

Comment: This is the definition of the differentiability, when partial differentials are known. Oh I did not notice you should add, after "It remains to show that the limit 

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-f_1(0,0)h-f_2(0,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

fails to exist":

"or exists but is $\ne0.$"

Comment: In my 1st comment to ["future readers"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699641), I meant "to disprove the differentiability at $(0,0)$", not "to disprove (1)".

Comment: Precisely. Or more generally: when the partial derivatives are $\alpha,\beta,$ the differential of $f$ must be $(h,k)\mapsto\alpha h+\beta k,$ or fail to exist. So, if $$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(h,k)-f(0,0)-\alpha h-\beta k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\ne0$$ (i.e. if the limit does not exist or is not $0$) then $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0).$