# Convex function: optimization

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, convex-optimization

### Problem statement

Use the deﬁnition of convexity of a function, i.e., that for any $\boldsymbol{x}$, $\boldsymbol{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $\lambda \in \left [0,1  \right ]$ we have
\begin{align*}
   f(\lambda \boldsymbol{x} +(1-\lambda)\boldsymbol{y} ) \leq \lambda f(\boldsymbol{x}) + (1-\lambda)f(\boldsymbol{y})
\end{align*}
to show that if f is convex and differentiable at $\boldsymbol{x}$ then
\begin{align*}
    f(\boldsymbol{y}) \geq f(\boldsymbol{x}) + \nabla f(\boldsymbol{x})^{\top} (\boldsymbol{y}-\boldsymbol{x})
\end{align*}
for all $\boldsymbol{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ (Use the definition of the directional derivative)

In order to get to the desired result, I have tried using the definition of a convex function together with an illustration. I am unsure whether my reasoning is correct and believe that there must be a way to derive this mathematically, but unfortunately I don't really have a strong maths background. I have found a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3331951/directional-derivatives-in-every-direction-for-a-convex-function-implies-differe), but it doesn't really answer my question.

### Attempted proof

[image: Proof by illustration]

### Summary

I have tried to prove this by illustration, but am looking for an analytical solution.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have \begin{align*}
   f(\lambda \boldsymbol{x} +(1-\lambda)\boldsymbol{y} ) \leq \lambda f(\boldsymbol{x}) + (1-\lambda)f(\boldsymbol{y})
\end{align*}

For scalar case divide above by $1-\lambda$

$f(y)=f(x)+\frac{f(x+(1-\lambda)(y-x))-f(x)}{1-\lambda}$.

Then take limit as $1-\lambda\rightarrow0$ to get what you want.