# Directional Derivatives and Linearity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Find an example of positive integers $n,m$, a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$, a point $a \in \mathbb{R}^m$, and nonzero vectors $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that the directional derivatives $f'(a;u), f'(a;v)$, and $f'(a;u+v)$ exist, but $f'(a;u+v) \neq f'(a;u) + f'(a;v)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use [this function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/372070/713897) with $m=2$, $n=1$, $a=(0,0)$, $u=(1,0)$ and $v=(0,1)$.