# Intuition behind the Boman's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, intuition, smooth-functions

I stumbled upon this result called  [Boman's Theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Boman%27s+theorem) twice last weak while working with the group of diffeomorphisms of a manifold and in a discussion with a friend about a certain function space.

> **Boman's Theorem:** A map $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is smooth if for every smooth curve $\gamma:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ we obtain the funcion $f\circ \gamma$ is smooth.

Nevertheless, I have no clue whatsoever why the result is true. I tried to understand it in the case $n=2$, but I had no success. I'm aware this result is sofisticated and is proved in **The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis**, by Michor and Kriegl.

Nevertheless, I don't want a profound understanding of the theorem, I just would like to undestand the intuition behind its validity.

> Question: What is the intuition behind Boman's theorem?

The result seems false to me because there are examples of non-smooth maps that maps lines in smooth functions like, for example,
$$f(x) = \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2},$$
extended to $0$ by continuity. This function maps every line through $0$ to a smooth curve, but [it's not differentiable at $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372070/f-not-differentiable-at-0-0-but-all-directional-derivatives-exist).

Comment: Look at Jan Boman's original article here https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10835/8856

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let  me try to answer. It is misleading to think of $\gamma$ as a curve. The image of a smooth function can be extremely irregular at points where all derivatives of the function vanish. To prove that an arbitrary directional derivative of $f$ must be bounded, I had to apply the assumption to functions $\gamma$ whose image contained infinitely many straight line segments with a fixed given direction at a given sequence of points. See formula (2.4) and the next few lines.

Comment: Thank you for answering! That is the exactly the kind of intuition I was looking for.