# Is a function differentiable if its directional derivatives converge uniformly on the unit vectors?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, we say that its directional derivatives converge in $\mathbf{a}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ uniformly with respect to the unit vectors if $\forall \varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that, for every $t \in B_\delta(0)$,
$$
\left|\frac{f(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{v})-f(\mathbf{a})}{t}-D_\mathbf{v}f(\mathbf{a})\right|<\varepsilon \quad \forall\, \mathbf{v}\,:\,\|\mathbf{v}\|=1
$$
where $D_\mathbf{v}f(\mathbf{a})$ denotes the direction derivative with respect to $\mathbf{v}$.

Now,
I know that the existence of all the directional derivatives doesn't guarantee the differentiability of a function, but I was wondering, what can we say if its directional derivatives converge uniformly on the unit vector? Intuitively I'd say that the function is also differentiable in $\mathbf{a}$, but I'm not exactly sure how to show it.

**Here's my attempt**: I'd like to show that $\lim_{{x} \to {a}} 
\frac{{f}({x})-{f}({a}) - {T}({x}-{a})}{\|{x}-{a}\|} = 0$ for some linear transformation $T$. Ignoring for a moment the part about the linear transformation, I can rewrite the first inequality as:
$$
\left|\frac{f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{a})-D_\mathbf{v}f(\mathbf{a})\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}\|}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}\|}\right|<\varepsilon \quad \forall\, \mathbf{x}\,:\,\|\mathbf{v}\|=1
$$

with $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{v}$ and $\|t \mathbf{v}\|=t=\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}\|$. At this point I'm stuck; maybe I'm missing something trivial. Did I do something wrong? Is the claim even true?

Comment: Doesn't the counterexample here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372070/show-that-fracx3x2y2-is-not-differentiable-at-0-0-even-though-al) satisfy your uniformity condition?