# Showing Multivariate Limit Doesn't Exist

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm reading an answer to another question on here and I'm not sure if I fully understand it. [Show that $\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, even though all directional derivatives exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372070/show-that-fracx3x2y2-is-not-differentiable-at-0-0-even-though-al/3582472#3582472)

The point I'm confused about is the end. It says:

> $\lim_{h \to 0} = \frac{-h_2^2h_1}{(h_1^2 + h_2^2)^{3/2}}.$

> If you let $h_1 = h_2m$ where $m \in \mathbb{R}$, then you can show this limit doesn't exist.

Here h is a vector and $h_1, h_2$ are the components. So I think what they're saying is that we can let $h_2$ go to 0 (WLOG) and then make a sequence of $h_1$ where $h_1 = mh_2$. Then $h_1$ will still go to 0 whatever the choice of m.

Plugging in, I got $\frac{-h_2^3m}{{(h_2^2m^2+h_2^2)}^{3/2}}$ = $\frac{{(-h_2^3m)}^{(2/3)}}{{h_2^2m^2+h_2^2}}$ = $\frac{{(h_2^2m^{(2/3)}}}{{h_2^2m^2+h_2^2}}$ = $\frac{m^{2/3}}{(m^2+1)}$. And then taking the limit obviously gives us $\frac{m^{2/3}}{(m^2+1)}$ since h has been eliminated.

And then I think the point here is that since m is arbitrary, we can make this limit achieve a lot of different values. So the limit has no definite value, i.e. doesn't exist. Is that right? I've just never seen this kind of argument before so not totally sure.

Comment: Basically the right idea, but your first equality is false; $A/B^{3/2}$ isn't equal to $A^{2/3}/B$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Oh right, good point.

Comment: The fact that the directional derivative  $f$ at the origin in the direction of $\vec{h}=(h_1,h_2)$ achieves many values depending on $\vec{h}$ doesn't imply that $f$ isn't differentiable at the origin. The dependency on $\vec{h}$ should be anticipated. For example, the directional derivative of $g(x,y)=x^2y^2+2$ at the point $(1,1)$ in the direction of $(h_1,h_2)$ equals $$\big(\vec{\nabla}{g}\big)(1,1)\cdot\vec{h}=2h_1+2h_2$$ which certainly depends on $\vec{h}$. What makes your $f$ not differentiable at the origin is the fact that your limit doesn't depend *linearly* on $\vec{h}$.

Comment: In the linked answer, the directional derivatives in the $x$ and $y$ directions are computed, and $\mathrm{D}f(0,0)$ is the linear function that would be the derivative, if $f$ was differentiable at $(0,0)$, so the final limit would exist and equal zero, if $f$ was differentiable. I don't know if it would help you, or be too confusing, but you could try reading the wikipedia articles on the Gateaux derivative and Frechet derivative.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Interesting, thanks.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the link. I had no idea linearity was related to this, so that's definitely helpful. I'm still confused as to how to show the limit doesn't exist though. And the Wikipedia page actually covers the function I asked about. I'm really confused as to how they got that the differential of the function is just the same thing as the function.

Comment: Using the definition in that wikipedia page, substitute in $u=(0,0)$ and the direction $\psi=(a,b)$, and you should find that all of the $\tau$ cancel out, yielding $\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: @Joe Yeah got it, thank you!

Comment: When you write "how to show the limit doesn't exist", do you mean the one in the answer you linked to? As you said, use any two distinct values of $m$ that don't yield the same limit - that shows that the limit doesn't exist, since limits in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ cannot depend on a particular path. In fact, just using $m=1$, and showing that if the limit exists, it doesn't equal zero, would also imply that the function isn't differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127651/discussion-between-lightnesscaster-and-joe).

Comment: I think you may still be confused about the two very different limits in the answer you linked to. The first limit is the limit definition of the directional derivative in the direction $(h_1, h_2)$. That limit exists for any direction (in this problem) but the fact that it's not a linear function of the direction (in particular, the dot product with the gradient) is one way to know that f isn't differentiable. The last limit in that answer, the one with the Df(0,0) in it, is the one that should be equal to zero if the function is differentiable, but in this problem that limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @Joe Got it, thank you!!