# why $Df(0,0)=(1,0)?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have some confusion on this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3057145/557708)

Consider the function :
$$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} , (x,y) \mapsto
  \begin{cases}
        0 & \text{for } (x,y)=(0,0) \\
   \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}       & \text{for } (x,y) \neq (0,0)
  \end{cases} $$

Show that $f$ not differentiable at $(0,0)$

It is  written that

> The Jacobi Matrix $A:=Df(0,0)=(1,0)$. Therefore if $f$ is differentiable $$\lim_{|\epsilon| \to 0}\frac{f(0+\epsilon)-f(0)-A\epsilon}{|\epsilon|}=0 .$$
> Since $f(0)=0$ and $A=(1,0)$ this is equivalent to,
> $$\lim_{|\epsilon| \to 0}\frac{f(\epsilon)-(1,0)\epsilon}{|\epsilon|}=0 $$

**My confusion** : Im not getting  why $Df(0,0)=(1,0)?$

Is there a formula/way to find out the value of $Df(0,0)$?

**My thinking** : $Df(0,0)= f_x(0,0) + f_y(0,0)$
$$
f_x(0, 0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h, 0)-f(0, 0)}{h}=1
$$

$$
f_y(0, 0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(0, k)-f(0, 0)}{k}=0
$$

Therefore $Df(0,0)= f_x(0,0) + f_y(0,0)=1+0=1 \neq (1,0)$

Comment: $Df(0,0)$ is not $f_x(0,0) + f_y(0,0)$ but $( f_x(0,0),  f_y(0,0))$.

Comment: @MartinR okay  thanks you

Comment: $Df(v)$ the the  $1\times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $$\lim_{|\epsilon|\to 0}\frac{f(v+\epsilon)-f(a,b)-A\epsilon}{|\epsilon|}=0.$$ This is by definition

Comment: You have to define it this way because you can't divide by $\epsilon.$ And using $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{f(v+\epsilon)-f(v)}{|\epsilon|}$$ will not work for regular real functions, because the limit will depend on whether $\epsilon$ goes to $0$ from the positive or negative side.

Comment: Whoops, too late to edit. Corrected comment: $Df(v)$ is the  $1\times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $$\lim_{|\epsilon|\to 0}\frac{f(v+\epsilon)-f(v)-A\epsilon}{|\epsilon|}=0.$$ This is by definition

Comment: @ThomasAndrews why did you not  take $(h,k) \to (0,0)$  instead  of $|\epsilon| \to 0$.Also  one  doubt ....Is $ (h,k)=\epsilon?$ yes/No

Comment: Yes, was just emulating the answer as given. But that answer turns out to be wrong, because the limit they assert is true is not true.

Comment: Oh, wait, the answer there isn't wrong. It just uses that **if** there is a derivative, it must be $(1,0).$ But it then proves that $(1,0)$ is not the derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer there doesn't say the derivative is $(1,0),$ only that, if there is a derivative, then it must be $(1,0).$ It then checks that answer, and the answer is found to not be the derivative.

The answer does have the right definition.

$Df(v)$ is the  $1\times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $$\lim_{|\epsilon|\to 0}\frac{f(v+\epsilon)-f(v)-A\epsilon}{|\epsilon|}=0.$$ This is by definition.

Now, if $A=(1,0)$ and $\epsilon=(e_1,e_2)$ and $v=(0,0),$ then:

$$f(\epsilon)-f(0)-A\epsilon=\frac{e_1^3}{e_1^2+e_2^2}-0-e_1=-\frac{e_1e_2^2}{e_1^2+e_2^2}$$

So $$\frac{f(\epsilon)-f(0)-A\epsilon}{|\epsilon|}=-\frac{e_1e_2^2}{(e_1^2+e_2^2)^{3/2}}$$

But if $e_2=e_1,$ the value is $\pm \frac1{2^{3/2}}$ depending on the signs of $e_1.$

And if $e_1=0,$ the value is $0.$

So the limit does not exist, and that answer is wrong.

---

If $A=(a_1,a_2)$ then:

$$f(\epsilon)-f(0)-A\epsilon=\frac{e_1^3}{e_1^2+e_2^2}-0-a_1e_1-a_2e_2=-\frac{(1-a_1)e_1^3
-a_1e_1e_2^2-a_2e_2^3-a_2e_1^2e_2}{e_1^2+e_2^2}$$

If $e_1=ke_2,$ for some real $k,$ then, after dividing by $|\epsilon|$ you get the limit:

$$\pm\frac{\left((1-a_1)k^3-a_1k -a_2k^2-a_3\right)}{2^{3/2}}$$

Depending on which direction $e_2$ approaches zero.

The limit will differ by different $k.$ in particular, the numerator will be non-zero for some $k,$ since it is a polynomial in $k$ with not all coefficients zero.

So there is no derivative.

---

The linked answer skips all the second section, using the result that, if $f$ has a derivative at $(0,0),$ it is: $$Df(0,0)=(D_1f(0,0),D_2f(0,0))=(1,0).$$

Comment: Im not getting why  $|e|= \sqrt {e_1^2 + e_2^2}?$

My thinking:  $|e| = \max\{e,-e\}=e=(e_1,e_2)$

Comment: When $e$ is a vector, $|e|$ is the length of the vector. When $e$ is a $1$-dimensional vector (a real number) we can think of $|e|=\pm e.$ But if $e=(1,1),$ what does $\max\{(1,),-(1,1)\}$ even mean? Two dimensional vectors are not naturally ordered. @jasmine

Comment: okay@Thomas Andrews  This means that  $e =(1,1)$ can be  written  as $1+i$.Okay  Got it.

Comment: Well, that works for $2$-dimensiona, but what about $(1,1,1)?$ It's not a question of complex numbers, but $n$-dimensional Euclidean geometry, and the generalization of the Pythagorean theorem. @jasmine