# On definition of Gâteaux derivative

Tags: analysis, definition, examples-counterexamples, gateaux-derivative

**Definition.** Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $f:U\rightarrow Y$ a map on an open subset $U\subset X$.

The map $f$ is called Gâteaux differential at $x\in U$ if there exists a continous linear map $A:X\rightarrow Y$ such that
$$\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{f(x+td)-f(x)}{t}=Ad,\forall d\in X$$
The $A$ then is called Gâteaux derivative of $f$.

I don't get the intuition ideal behind the condition $A$ is linear (and moreover continous). Why we define it that way and what happens if $A$ is not linear (or continous)? (particularly in finite and infinite dimensional spaces)

Comment: What definition of derivative do you like in multivariable Calculus? In finite dimensional vector calculus if $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is (Frechet) differentiable at $x$ then it turns out that $D_v f(x) = f’(x) v$ for all $v$. But this suggests an alternative definition of a differentiable function which is that $f$ is Gateaux differentiable at $x$ iff there exists a vector $g$ such that $D_v f(x) = g \cdot v$ for all $v$. We might wonder if this alternative definition of a differentiable function turns out to be equivalent to Frechet differentiability

Comment: @littleO I mean why in general we must have $A$ is linear and what if $A$ is just a normal map?

Comment: This example might be interesting to look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372070/show-that-fracx3x2y2-is-not-differentiable-at-0-0-even-though-al

Comment: What a derivative does is describing the linear map approximating $f$ close to $x$ in the best way. If you think of derivatives of functions on $\mathbb{R}$, it is the slope of the tangent to the graph. The tangent is a straight line, not any curve. Without the restriction to linear maps, the whole notion of derivatives would become irrelevant. The best way to approximate a function without any restrictions is just taking the function itself. But defining a derivative of a function just as the function itself does not help anybody.

Comment: @Tzimmo Thank you for your insight.