# Show that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if $f(tx+(1-t)a)$ has derivative at $0$ for all $x$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces

In the book ["A Graduate Course on Statistical Inference"](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=3OOmDwAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PR5&dq=A%20Graduate%20Course%20on%20Statistical%20Inference%20(Bing%20Li)&hl=pt-BR&pg=PA12#v=onepage&q&f=false) (as you can see in this link) there's the following passage: "[a function] $f(\theta )$ is differentiable at $\theta _0$ if and only if, for every $\theta$ in a neighborhood $\theta_0$, the function $f((1-t)\theta_0+t\theta )$ is differentiable with respect to $t$ at $t=0$".

I think what the book meant is:

> Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ be open, $a\in U$ and $f:U\to
>  \mathbb{R}$. Then the following propositions are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f$ is differentiable at $a$
> 2. There're $r,s>0$ such that the function $g_x:(-s,s)\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g_x(t):=f(tx+(1-t)a)$ is well defined and has derivative at
>    $0$ for all $x\in B_r(a)\subseteq U$.

**My questions are:** Did I understand correctly what the book meant? If no, what did the book want to say? If yes, how can I prove that implication $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$?

---

I was able to prove the implication $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$, however I don't know how to prove that other implication.

I know that if there is an open neighborhood $V$ of $a$ such that $V\to \mathbb{R},x\mapsto \partial_i f(x)$ exists and is continuous at $a$ for all $i\in \{1,\cdots,m\}$, then $f$ is differentiable at $a$. However I don't know how to prove this.

Help me to prove that implication please.

---

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: I’m starting to think that the book’s authors are referring to Gauteax differentiability, because considering only those conditions I don’t think that is possible to prove that $f$ is Frechet differentiable at $a$.

Comment: The author writes that $f$ is a "p-variate" function. You should explain what this means. For a general $f$ it is not true that the existence of all directional derivatives implies that $f$ is differentiable-

Comment: @PaulFrost I think that “p-variate” means that domain of $f$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true. The requirement

> For every $\theta$ in a neighborhood $\theta_0$ [which we call $V$], the function $f((1-t)\theta_0+t\theta)$ is differentiable with respect to $t$ at $t=0$

means nothing else than that there exist all directional derivatives of $f$ at $\theta_0$. In fact, consider $f_{\theta}(t) := f((1-t)\theta_0+t\theta) = f(\theta_0 + t(\theta - \theta_0))$.

For each $v \in \mathbb R^p$  there exists $r > 0$ such that $\theta_0 + tv \in V$ for $\lvert t \rvert \le r$. Let $\theta =  \theta_0 + rv$.  Then
$$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(\theta_0) = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(\theta_0 + tv)- f(\theta_0)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(\theta_0 + t\frac{\theta - \theta_0}{r})- f(\theta_0)}{t} \\= r\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{f(\theta_0 + \frac t r (\theta - \theta_0){})- f(\theta_0)}{\frac t r} = r\lim_{s \to 0}\frac{f(\theta_0 + s (\theta - \theta_0){})- f(\theta_0)}{s} \\= r\lim_{s \to 0}\frac{f_\theta(s) -f_\theta(0)}{s} = rf'_\theta(0).$$

It is well-known that the existence of all directional derivatives of $f$ at $\theta_0$ does not imply that $f$ is differentiable at $\theta_0$. For an example see [Show that $\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, even though all directional derivatives exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/372070).